# Throttle message rate for subscribers

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a publisher with a high data rate (approx. 100 Hz) and multiple subscribers. One of them requires the full data rate, while another is quite happy with one message per second.

My simple solution for the latter is to process every 100th message only, but I was wondering if ROS provides a more elegant solution, such as a message filter or a subscription option which lets me choose the desired message rate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11264/throttle-message-rate-for-subscribers/) by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1951 on 2011-09-20

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In fact, ROS does. What you're looking for is the `drop` node from [topic_tools](http://www.ros.org/wiki/topic_tools).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-09-20**:
Thanks for the link. In this particular instance, I would prefer a way to control the rate from within my own node (C++), but I'll keep this package in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For future reference, [REP 106](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0106.html) on polled topics is proposed for Fuerte.

Among other things, that will allow an individual subscriber to request that the publisher transmit messages at a lower frequency.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-07-30**:\

> the REP has been updated to **Withdrawn** because the proposed functionality will not be implemented for the current ROS client libraries`